# How can I compute the complement of a mathematical membership function?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, machine-learning, neural-networks, fuzzy-logic, fuzzy-set

Considering fuzzy set A defined on real numbers by the membership functions:

$\mu_A(x)=\frac{1}{x+1}, \mu_C(x)=\frac{1}{10^x}$

How can I determine mathematical membership function and graph of 
$ A \cap \overline{C}$ ?

*Till know I have tried the above :*

Let A be a fuzzy set in the universe of information say U. Then, A can be defined as a set of ordered pairs represented mathematically as $A = \{(g,\mu_A(g)): g \in U\}$ where $\mu_A(g)$ is the degree of membership of $g$. Also, the range for the membership function is 
$\mu_A \in [0,1]$ .

$ A \cap \overline{C}$ = {(g,$\mu_{A \cap \overline{C}}(g)): g \in$ U}

> I am stuck on how I can compute the **complement of $C \equiv\overline{C}$** ?

Considering $A \cap \overline{C} = \{(g,min(\mu_A(g), 1-\mu_C(g)) : g \in$ U }

How can I represent this set graphically ?

[image: Graphic]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A \cap \overline{C} = \{(g,min(\mu_A(g), 1-\mu_C(g))) : g \in U \}$

Comment: So $\mu_{\neg C}(x)=1- \frac{1}{10^x}$ ?